# "more" button with text truncation in tvOS doesn't work

Tags: tvos, apple-tv

I use `tvml` to develop tvOS app.

Because of long text in description, the system cuts the long text into short description with `more` button.

However, the `more` button doesn't work. Once click the button, it doesn't show up anything, and it's supposed to pop up a screen with all descriptions inside.

Below is part of code. If you can help me, I really appreciate it!

```
<document>
  <head>
    <style>
    </style>
  </head>
  <compilationTemplate theme="dark">
    <list>
      <relatedContent>
        <itemBanner>
          <heroImg src="${this.BASEURL}images/stackImage/stack01.png" width="650" height="650" />
        </itemBanner>
      </relatedContent>
      <header>
        <title>This is a title</title>
        <subtitle>Aware</subtitle>
        <row>
          <text>120 minutes</text>
        </row>
      </header>
      <section>
        <description allowsZooming="true">This is the long description!This is the long description!This is the long description!This is the long description!This is the long description!This is the long description!
        </description>
      </section>
      <section>
        <listItemLockup autoHighlight="true" videoURL="videoURL">
          <ordinal minLength="2">1</ordinal>
          <title>This is the subject</title>
          <decorationLabel>15:28</decorationLabel>
        </listItemLockup> 
  </section>
</list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually code the part that listens to the click on the more button, and present the full text in a an alert view. This functionality does not come automatically with the description component. [Check out this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/126250/tvml-tutorial-using-tvml-templates) for the details. Go to the sections called "Handling text overflow", and you will see how to do it.